# Figure with some columns stacked, some not stacked

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make the following figure, but am not sure it is possible to mix rows and columns like this.

[image]

The example dataframe would be:

```
trt   rain   evap   drain   runoff  balance
cc    10     3       2        1      4
ccw   10     2       2        3      3
cs    10     4       1        2      3
sc    10     3       3        3      1
```

Rain is the input; evap, drain, and runoff the outputs, and balance the difference between the input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trt <- c("cc", "ccw", "cs", "sc")
rain <-  c(10,10,10,10)
evap <- c(3,2,4,3)
drain <- c(2,2,1,3)
runoff <- c(1,3,2,3)
balance <- c(4,3,3,1)


dat <- data.frame(trt,rain,evap, drain , runoff ,balance)    
bp <-  barplot(t(as.matrix(dat[,c(3,4,5)] )), col=c("blue","red", "yellow"), cex.axis=1, cex.names=1,names.arg=trt, xlab="Treatment", ylab="Amount", xlim=c(-2, 10), yaxt="n", ylim=c(0,20))

par(new=TRUE)
rect(-1,0,-2,15,col='lightblue')

par(new=TRUE)
for(i in 1:length(balance)){
 rect(4.2+i,0,5+i,balance[i],col='green')  
  axis(1,at=(4.5+i), trt[i],tick=F )
}


text(7, 6, "Balance")
text(-1, 17, "Input\n(same for all)")
text(3, 10, "Outputs")
```

[image]